# Choosing waterproof or protected GPIO connectors

Tags: connector, gpio, waterproof

I am building a small device that, with the others, has several (at least 8) GPIOs and will be placed outside or, at best, in a possibly wet/humid environment. I am having a hard time finding a small connector model that I can use for these purposes.

What are the typical solutions for this scenario?

Please consider that the request is for 2 poles connectors and I am looking for reasonably priced options as the device will need at least 8.

So far, the best I could think of was several 3.5mm jacks (one per GPIO): they are cheap  and easy to plug/unplug but I think they are sub-optimal and not really waterproof.

I was also considering designing and printing my custom ones but this also seems futile.

Both PCB soldered and panel mount solutions are acceptable.

Comment: You want something with a suitable IP rating https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_code

Comment: Personally, I have "weatherproofed" a WiFi router by covering its PCB/components with acrylic coating (nail polish) and placed its connectors on the lower side so that rain/water is less likely to get in and can drip out if it does happen to get inside. So far, it has been working for probably about 2 years on top of my house. What's worse, I placed it on top of my chimney which is used for wood stove and often has smoke coming out. But a watertight enclosure would be better. Don't ignore the small insects messing up your connectors as well, and protect or plug them with something.

Comment: @LordTeddy I don't have strict requirements but I assume that anything from IP53 to IP67 would do. Needless to say that IP67 would be much better played.

Comment: @EdinFifić I know the technique you used and it works in many situations but nothing like this would work for my case: I should be able to plug/unplug connectors over time and while I can create a completely sealed box for the main device, I need to also protect its connectors.

Comment: Then you should use rubber or rubberized plug covers which are possibly attached to the body and can be easily put on and taken off. Some mobile phones and similar devices have used the same technique.

Comment: @EdinFifić this is an interesting idea to investigate. I am not sure I ever seen something like this but a soft rubber sheath around both ends of the connectors may actually do. Anything you can show from real world stuff that I don't need to engineer myself?

Comment: @FedericoStango Just search for "waterproof audio jack" or "waterproof audio connector".  Here is an iPhone with the type of plug  I mentioned: https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/550a10cbe4b03c7ec206488b/1427530768628-VTNT807DETB2CGZHOJW8/lifeproof_nuud_waterproof_rugged_case_for_iphone_5c_headphone_port_watertight_plug.jpg  It is actually a case for iPhone: LifeProof Nuud iPhone 5c Waterproof Case

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another answer, based on the additional crucial requirements that OP added in a comment, that were not in the original question.

For a cheap, 2-pin, waterproof connector,  my [Select-a-conn utility](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=S&a=--W---&c=-w----------) has another suggestion: [e-bike connectors](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NN&n=ebike_circ_conn). Manufacturers include:

- [Jun Ley](http://www.junleidq.com/product/60.html), under the brand name of Julet, sold on [Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=Julet), AliExpress
- [Higo](https://www.higoconnector.com/products#product-modal), sold by AC Solutions

[image: Higo connectors]

{A&C Solutions}

They are not PCB-mount (panel-mount is available), but they are cheap and effective.

Comment: Thanks Davide, I see that this company has many connectors, also with panel mount options. I'm browsing the various solution but this is pretty much what I was looking for.

Answer (score 6):

I looked for a small, waterproof, wire-to-board connector in my [Select-a-conn utility](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=S&a=--W---&c=-w----------). Of the suggested results, I picked the [IEC circular connectors, M12 code A](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NN&n=iec_m12_circular_conn&&fl=000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000-140-%7C9%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C).

https://www.digikey.com/short/9m922zff

[image: M12 connectors]

{Digikey}

Comment: Thanks, this is pretty much where it all started but none of these kind of connectors are cheap for a device that is supposed to have 8. Also and more important this has many pins while I need 8 different connectors, each with 2 pins basically. I will take a look at the utility (seems very useful) and further prune the list in Digikey but as far as I remember these connectors won't be a viable option.

Comment: " I need 8 different connectors". You would have saved time by stating that in the body of your question.  "cheap". That would have been nice to know in advance as well.

Comment: That is actually written in the body but I believe I should have made that more clear as the wording could be misunderstood.

Comment: It is not. (8 GPIOs is understood to mean 8 wires in a single connector, not 8 separate connectors.) Please edit your question so others won't be send on a wild goose chase.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with others that if you want a reliable waterproof connector you will need to buy one with an IP rating, and install it properly.

It is important to note that m12 connectors that are unplugged may still corrode in harsh environments, since the contacts will be getting wet. Probably true of the ebike connectors as well. They do make caps for m12 connectors, and if you go that route you should provide them for any unused IO.

There are other possible solutions. For example, you may be able to build a cable gland into your device, and keep the connectors inside where it's dry. If the the device does not need to be installed while wet, this is arguably a better solution.

On my sons RC car, the solution they use is a slot through which many cables can be passed. Once the cables are installed a plate with a foam gasket is tightened over the slot. The foam seals the slot and conforms to the cables, preventing water ingress.

Comment: That gasket idea is good, but you need quite a specific foam - it must be closed cell to keep the water out, but conform well enough to the cables that it makes a seal.  Without either buying something ready-made or extensive prototyping, it's probably best considered only splash-proof

Comment: @ChrisH I guess splash-proof is all that's needed for the car, which isn't meant to drive underwater, and perhaps also for the asker's application, which we don't know.

Comment: @user253751 exactly - a good idea that they may be able to use but not unquestioningly.